# How to sort more than 3 columns in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sort more than 3 columns in VBA. When I add key4, it shows "Named argument not found." How can I handle this? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SubLieutenant_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long


LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("F6:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(C6, Today(),""y"")+DateDif(E6, Today(), ""d"")/30"

Range("A6").Sort key1:=Range("F6"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("E6"), order2:=xlAscending, key3:=Range("D6"), order3:=xlAscending, key4:=Range("C6"), order4:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't make much sense as it's sorting one cell?

But for a real example you just select the actual range first
then add the sort keys separately instead of in one line

```
With ActiveSheet
   .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End With

With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:G6")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: can't handle for this. How can I?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BygyhjskixC9OHRfNWVmbjljcVk

Comment: I would use `.SetRange Range("A1:G6")` instead of `.SetRange Range("A1:D6")`

Answer (score 0):

use below mentioned lines for sorting. Sort the data twice on different columns.

```
Range("A6").Sort key1:=Range("C6"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Range("A6").Sort key1:=Range("F6"), order1:=xlDescending, _
        key2:=Range("E6"), order2:=xlAscending, _
        key3:=Range("D6"), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: This will ignore the first sort when it performs the second sort.  The OP wants:  Sort by, Then by, Then by, Then, by.  Your code is: Sort by, Sort by, Then by, Then by.  Key2 and Key3 are "secondary" sorts of Key1.  As the Key4 argument doesn't exist in VBA, there is no way to accomplish the OP's need with the older .Sort method.  You must use the .SortFields.Add method as @dbmitch illustrated in his correct answer.